# Word for preventing, remediating or mitigating a problem

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In cybersecurity there are the following terms:

- *prevention*: preventing a cybersecurity attack before it even begins, or just as it begins, such that no material damage or impact on the target system exists; and
- *remediation*: stopping on ongoing cybersecurity attack; some material damage (the initial attack) may be had but, after remediation, that damage stops; and
- *mitigation*: reducing the impact (but not outright stopping) a cybersecurity attack so as to minimize the damage sustained

I'm looking for a word that describes all three. That is, to either prevent, remediate or mitigate a problem.

---

**Example usage:** "*Oh how I wish I had a tool that would help me prevent, remediate or mitigate these cybersecurity attacks.*"

Comment: Please give a sentence where you would use the word. There are many things you could call them, _steps, measures, procedures_ and the list could go on. You must give a context that can limit the choices.

Comment: Thanks @fev (+1) -- understood and I have updated my question with an example usage sentence!

Comment: Where did you get these 3 definitions? Can you add a reference and/or link?  I thought remediation was mean a fix/solution be applied to a vulnerability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can address a problem through prevention, remediation, or mitigation.  Strictly speaking "addressing" an issue states that you're speaking about it.  However, we will sometimes use "address" as a word to mean that the problem was thoughtfully approached and acted on.

According to the [vDict dictionary](https://vdict.pro/en-en/addressing):

Address means to

> think about and begin to deal with (an issue or problem).
> "a fundamental problem has still to be addressed"

If English is not your first language, it may be wise to use a some extra words to ensure you're well understood.

> We found 21 potential issues and have addressed them as follows:
>
> *We have provided code and configuration to prevent 18 vulnerabilities from being exploited.
> *There is evidence of three tier-three incidents which are being remediated through joint work sessions with your lead system engineers
> and developers.
> *We suspect one of those three incidents may have lead to a significant breach.  I will update you as I know more.  It is nearly
> impossible to know the full extent of most breaches.  We are working
> to mitigate the compromise to integrity and confidentiality of your
> data by comparing your backups.  In the mean time, you and I should speak
> with PR, HR, and legal to consider our options and obligations.

You could also "resolve" an issue by preventing or remediating.

Source:  I'm an English-only CISSP w/ 15+ years professionally in cybersecurity.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for ***combat***:

> to struggle against 
> especially : to strive to reduce or eliminate
>
> - combat pollution ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/combat))

So you need

> a tool to ***combat*** cybersecurity attacks.

The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combat%20cyber%20attacks&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccombat%20cyber%20attacks%3B%2Cc0) for the expression ***combat cyber attacks*** (not cybersecurity attacks) is quite impressive.

Answer (score 1):

A word that may cover your need is **alleviate**. It works well for *remediating* and *mitigating* but its application to *preventing* is less secure, although arguable as below.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/alleviate)
> *alleviate*:
> to make pain or problems less severe
> *We hope this study will alleviate this concern.*

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/alleviate-the-need)
> *alleviate*:
> to reduce or decrease
> *The new battery could alleviate the concerns of many potential electric car buyers about running out of power.*
> *In 1938, the school's annex was constructed to alleviate the need for portable classrooms.*

It may be argued that the *concerns* and *need* in these examples are things that are foreseeable and are therefore *prevented* by alleviation.

Hence, "*I wish I had a tool that would help me alleviate these cybersecurity attacks.*"